# Return an array of a single property from an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for an way to return an array of only a single property of an array of objects in Javascript. Specifically, if I have an array structure formatted to the following specification:

```
[
    { prop1: "someVar", prop2: "anotherVar" }, 
    { prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar" }, 
    { prop1: "abc", prop2: "def" }
]
```

How can I return an array of just the `prop1` properties? Like following:

```
[ "someVar", "foo", "abc" ]
```

I thought I could simply use the .`filter` method on my original array, like so:

```
self.myArray.filter(function (el) {
        return el.prop1;
    });
```

But that clearly doesn't work... Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this;

```
var newArray = [
    { prop1: "someVar", prop2: "anotherVar" }, 
    { prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar" }, 
    { prop1: "abc", prop2: "def" }
].map(function(item) {
    return item.prop1;
});
```

In case `prop1` is dynamic then you can have a function like;

```
function extractProperty(array, prop) { //you may want to give it a better name
    return array.map(function(item) {
        return item[prop]; 
    });
}
```

You can use it like;

```
var array = extractProperty([
    { prop1: "someVar", prop2: "anotherVar" }, 
    { prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar" }, 
    { prop1: "abc", prop2: "def" }
], 'prop1');
```

Comment: Gotta think op wants "prop1" (e.g. which property) to be dynamic

Comment: Yep - exactly. I deleted my answer that was the same, nice answer. +1

Comment: The formal computer-sciencey data-sciency name for it would be `project`, in case anyone cares.

Comment: @renatoargh, thanks for the solution. Yep, the property in question is not dynamic but it's nice to know what would be needed in case it was dynamic. Cheers.

Comment: Also, when you ever get into cool libraries, like underscore.js, you can just use [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) which is already in the library for you.

Comment: Underscore came up while I was looking for answers, and it definitely looks neat. Thanks for the tip!